# == comparisons against lines from readlines() fail

Tags: python, anagram, readlines

I am currently working on a small anagram program that takes all possible permutations of a word and compare them with a dictionary.  However, I am unable to get the results to print. The culprit appears to be the == operator, if I put `''.join(words[i]) == compare[j]` nothing prints, however, if I input hi and run the program with `''.join(words[i]) == "hi"` the entire dictionary prints, but if I invert it to `"hi" == compare[j]` nothing prints.

Thanks in advance for any help!

```
import itertools

run = input("Please enter a word: ")
dictionary = "dictionary.txt" #input("Please enter the name of the dictionary file: ")
txt = open(dictionary)

compare = txt.readlines()

words = (list(itertools.permutations(run)))

for i in range(0, len(words)):
    for j in range(0, len(compare)):
        if ''.join(words[i]) == compare[j]:
            print(compare[j])
```

Comment: Note that when you say you inverted it, you didn't. I suggest you debug by printing all variables involved. From what you've gathered so far the problem seems to be `compare[j]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
compare = txt.readlines()
```

`readlines()` doesn't strip the line endings from each line, so each line will have a `\n` at the end. That causes all your comparisons against `compare[j]` to fail.

You could remove the `\n`'s with something like.

```
compare = [line.strip() for line in txt]
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that if your word has `W` letters, and your dictionary has `D` words, your search is doing `W! * D` comparisons.

You can reduce this to `D` comparisons by converting both words to canonical form (ie letters in alphabetical order).

If you are going to search for `N` words you could reduce it further to `D / N` comparisons per word (amortized) by storing your dictionary as `{canonical_form: [list,of,matching,words]}`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

DICT_FILE = "dictionary.txt"

def canonize(word):
    # "hello\n" => "ehllo"
    return "".join(sorted(word.strip()))

def load_dict(fname=DICT_FILE):
    lookup = defaultdict(list)
    with open(fname) as inf:
        for line in inf:
            word = line.strip()
            canon = canonize(word)
            lookup[canon].append(word)
    # lookup["ehllo"] = ["hello"]
    return lookup

def main():
    anagrams = load_dict()
    while True:
        word = input("Enter word to search for (or hit Enter to quit): ").strip()
        if not word:
            break
        else:
            canon = canonize(word)
            if canon in anagrams:
                print("Found: " + ", ".join(anagrams[canon]))
            else:
                print("No anagrams found.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

which then runs like

```
Enter word to search for (or hit Enter to quit): tester
Found: retest, setter, street, tester

Enter word to search for (or hit Enter to quit): binary
Found: binary, brainy

Enter word to search for (or hit Enter to quit): ttt
No anagrams found.

Enter word to search for (or hit Enter to quit):
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace the newlines from the variable:

```
compare = compare.replace('\n', '')
```